# hiding application bar in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to hide application bar in windows phone application like this : `appbar1.IsVisible=false;`
but when i debug the code , an error occurs `NullReferenceException` at the same line . why ? need help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false;`

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
ApplicationBar = ((ApplicationBar)this.Resources["appbar1"])
ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false;
```

This will solve your issue

Comment: i have tried your code but same error occured again

Comment: Can you check whether this.Resources["appbar1"] (in Quick watch) have also returns null? if it is then 'this' you used is not referening to the page where you are having the application bar

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try this code.

```
ApplicationBar _Appbar= ((ApplicationBar)this.Resources["appbar1"]);  _Appbar.IsVisible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ApplicationBarIconButton btn = (ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[0];
                    btnResend.IsEnabled = false;
```